# Azure functions disable logging not successful

Tags: python, logging, azure-functions, python-logging

When running my Azure function locally, I'm getting lots of logging messages which I'd like to disable, e.g.

```
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z] Response status: 200
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z] Response headers:
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'Pragma': 'no-cache'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'Expires': '-1'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'x-ms-keyvault-region': 'germanywestcentral'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'x-ms-client-request-id': 'xxx'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'x-ms-request-id': 'xxx'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'x-ms-keyvault-service-version': '1.9.713.1'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'x-ms-keyvault-network-info': 'conn_type=Ipv4;addr=xxx;act_addr_fam=InterNetwork;'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'Date': 'Wed, 01 Mar 2023 12:45:14 GMT'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.038Z]     'Content-Length': '458'
```

or

```
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z] Request URL: 'https://xxx.file.core.windows.net/xxx/xxx.xlsx'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z] Request method: 'PUT'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z] Request headers:
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z]     'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z]     'x-ms-content-length': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z]     'x-ms-type': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z]     'x-ms-file-permission': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z]     'x-ms-file-attributes': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z]     'x-ms-file-creation-time': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z]     'x-ms-file-last-write-time': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.992Z]     'Accept': 'application/xml'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.993Z]     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-file-share/12.10.1 Python/3.9.16 (macOS-13.1-arm64-arm-64bit)'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.993Z]     'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.993Z]     'x-ms-client-request-id': 'xxx'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.993Z]     'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
[2023-03-01T12:45:15.993Z] No body was attached to the request
[2023-03-01T12:45:16.100Z] Response status: 201
```

I tried:

```
    client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential, logging=False)
    ....
    # upload file to share
    file_client = ShareFileClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str='xxx',
        share_name=container_name,
        file_path=file_name,
        logging_enable=False,
    )
```

I still would like to be able to create logging output from within my app, e.g. `logging.info('example message')`

But, how can I disable the above HTTP logging?

Answer (score 0):

Setting logging to false using `client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential, logging=False)` does not affect the logging of the function, only of the key vault communication. Setting it to false prevents Detailed DEBUG level logging, including request/response bodies and unredacted headers. But it still emits INFO level logging which includes basic information about HTTP sessions (URLs, headers, etc.) ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-python#logging))

To specify what should be logged by the azure function runtime and your application and consumed services you need to modify the `host.json` file as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels). An example:

```json
{
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Warning",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Error",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```